# How do I add a ViewPager as the top item in my ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, rotator

I have a vanilla "News" app, where the main page is a ListView that scrolls vertically with a list of articles (thumbnail, title..etc).  This works just fine, but now I want to add a horizontal article/photo rotator as the top item in that list.  I don't really care if it's technically in the list or not, but it should scroll up/off the screen when the list is dragged...etc.  I assume(d) it should be in the list, but am quite new to Android and don't know if there's a better solution.

After an entire day of searching around, I'm still empty-handed - don't know how to add it or even if it's the right method.  I'm using a ViewPager for my gallery view (when they click a photo), and that seems to be working fine...but that's the entire view... and this one already has an adapter that populates the listView... I hope I'm just over-complicating something.

**TLDR**:

```
1) Can I add a ViewPager as top item in a ListView?
2) How would one go about doing it?
3) Is there a better solution?
```

Note: android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `addHeaderView()` from the ListView API to set a header. It can be any View, so also a ViewPager. I think you'll have to add it programmatically. Set the height of it correctly though.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i understand your question. `ViewPager` is a view like any other, so in your `ListView`'s adapter's `getView()` method, return a view that contains a `ViewPager`.

`ViewPager` is a topic in itself, so if your problem is that you don't understand `ViewPager`, read these links,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html
>
> http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

if you are using API level 8, you should use the `ViewPager` and friends from the compatibility package.

that all being said, i wonder if you will have trouble putting a scrollable view inside a scrollable view. i know `ViewPager` contains code to pass off any gestures to child views if it decides it cannot handle them. i can't say if `ListView` has the same smarts.

Comment: I don't even call the getView() that I can find.   In a for() loop, I do: `articleEntryAdapter.add(a1);`, yet I don't see an "add()" method in that file...

Comment: I mean... I have a lot of logic in getView, but...  how do I tell it when to "add" my other view?  And where do I put the logic to populate that view?

Comment: okay, are you using a custom adapter? that allows you complete control over the building of each view of the listview. just google on the topic and you'll find lots of information.

Comment: I guess I am - I have a lot of my own code in getView() method.  Per my question, Googling all day has led to nothing.

Comment: if you are / were not sure if you have a custom adapter, i suspect you need to spend some time on that topic. essentially, you return a View object from getView(). that can be whatever you want. you can inflate a view from XML, or build it manually by new'ing various view objects. regardless, ViewPager is just another type of view can be part of the tree of View objects you return from getView().